# Why HANDLE created by 'CreateEvent' isn't valid in another process?

Tags: c++, winapi, handle, win32-process

I am writing an ant-cheat Win32 loader and in it I need to create an event, wait for it to get signaled by another process in which I have stored it - but it's failing with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. I am creating an unnamed event and just passing it's HANDLE value into the other process which should set it to signaled state in certain condition. Any ideas why is this - isn't the HANDLE created by 'CreateEvent' valid for all proceses. Pseudo code illustrating this:

Process1, Thread1:

```
extern LPVOID pExternalMemory;

extern HANDLE hExternalProcess; //Process2 Handle

extern HANDLE hExternalThread; //In suspended state (Thread1)

extern HANDLE hEventDuplicate;

HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, true, false, nullptr);

DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hEvent, hExternalProcess, &hEventDuplicate, STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL, false, 0); //Wrong, check EDIT1

WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pExternalMemory, &hEventDuplicate, sizeof(HANDLE), nullptr);

ResumeThread(hExternalThread);

WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
```

Process2, Thread1:

EIP->

```
if(SomeCondition) SetEvent((HANDLE)ExternalMemory); //fails with 'ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE'

//Other code
```

EDIT: I used 'DuplicateHandle' to fix the problem but now 'SetEvent' call on second process fails with 'ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED'.

EDIT1: Solved the problem - it was with the 'DuplicateHandle' function call, it should be

```
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hEvent, hExternalProcess, &hEventDuplicate, 0, false, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
```

For some strange reason - anyone can explain why is this?

Comment: Why not? Because they're not. There are ways to get around it though, `DuplicateHandle` being one of them.

Comment: Yep I see. But I remember that somewhere I read events are used for process sync.

Comment: Events can be shared between processes. But each process needs its own handle to the event. Handles are specific to a process.

Comment: I did share it but now it fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED!

Comment: Where is the call to `DuplicateHandle`? What parameters did you use?

Comment: `STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL` *only* includes the [standard access rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379607(v=vs.85).aspx) which are common to all kinds of securable objects.  It doesn't include object-specific access rights.  The documentation for SetEvent specifies that you need the object-specific access right `EVENT_MODIFY_STATE`.  So, it would probably work if you said `STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL|EVENT_MODIFY_STATE` but it is conceptually simpler to use `DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handles are kinda like pointers in that they're usually process-specific. It takes special actions (like using DuplicateHandle) to share them.

Depending on the situation, it might just be easier to name the object and then have the other process access it that way. See the fourth parameter of [CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).